# Invertible matrix which can't be row reduced to $I$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

What is an example of a ring $R$, where if $A \in M_{n}(R)$ is invertible, then we *cannot* row reduce $A$ to $I$?

Comment: Sorry, is my question clearer?

Comment: Clear enough and non-trivial. There are examples of $2\times 2$ matrices over PIDs which are not products of elementary matrices. A simpler example can be given over $K[X,Y]$: $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1-XY&-Y^2\\X^2&1+XY\end{array}\right)$. (Btw, row reduced to $I$ is equivalent of being a product of elementary matrices.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, and I have simplified my post just to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no: not every invertible matrix with entries in a PID is a product of elementary matrices. However, every invertible matrix with entries in a Euclidean domain is. I don't think there is a brief counterexample, but you can take a look at [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251103/principal-ideal-ring-does-there-exist-an-invertible-matrix-such-that-certain-ma) if it interests you. However, things cannot get too bad: there is an algorithm for general PIDs which applies a $2 \times 2$ invertible matrix operation in addition to elementary operations, which can reduce any invertible matrix to the identity.

Comment: Thanks, I think i forgot to add a condition in my initial argument. I believe Smith Normal form works on PID: so exists $Q,P$ invertible such that $QAP=D$, where $D$ is diagonal. Then $\det (QAP) = \det(D) =1 \Rightarrow \det(D)$ is unit as all $Q,A,P$ are invertible. Hence, we may row multiply $D$, making $D=I$. So my quoted statement holds for entries in PID? What went wrong if this is not true?

Comment: What if $Q$ or $P$ cannot be expressed as a product of elementary matrices? This is what it comes down to: in an arbitrary PID, not all invertible matrices are products of elementary matrices.

Comment: Yes, I see it now, thanks a lot.